# ARCore: How to detect HitTest on the infinite extension of a detected plane?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to detect the hitTests on the infinite extension of a defined detected plane.

I see that there is isHitInPolygon() but too restrictive. There is also isPoseInExtents but detects the hits only the overall rectangular surface.

How to detect a HitTest on the infinite extension of a detected plane ? A workaround would be to modify the size of the plane but does not seem possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you solve this?